# Nested dollar signs inside quotes

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to write a bash script containing nested dollar variables and I can't get it to work :

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '4s/.*/$(grep "remote.*$1" /home/txtfile)/' /home/target
```

The error says :

> sed / -e expression #1, char 30: unkown option to 's'

The problem seems to come from $1 which need to be replaced by the parameter passed from the bash call and then the whole `$(...)` needs to be replaced by the command call so we replace the target line 4 by the string output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable expansion and Command substitution won't be done when put inside single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
sed "4s/.*/$(grep "remote.*$1" /home/txtfile)/" /home/target
```

Comment: That will produce nasal demons given various input values and/or the contents of the directory you execute it from since `remote.*$1` is unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, the right way to do what you want is just one command, something like this (depending on your possible `$1` values and input file contents which you haven't shown us):

```
awk -v tgt='remote.*$1' '
NR==FNR { if ($0 ~ tgt) str = str $0 ORS; next }
FNR==4  { printf "%s", str; next }
{ print }
' /home/txtfile /home/target
```